# Convert a list of tuples (from itertools) into a list of words in a text file, Python

Tags: python, python-itertools, iterable-unpacking

I'm using:

```
list(it.permutations(wordlist, 3))
```

and am getting a result as a list of tuples, such as:

```
[('mom', 'dad', 'kid'), ('mom', 'dad', 'house'), ('mom', 'dad', 'car'), ('mom', 'dad', 'happy'), ('mom', 'dad', 'Hello'), ('mom', 'dad', 'goodbye'), ('mom', 'dad', 'covid'), ('mom', 'dad', 'influenza'), ('mom', 'dad', 'cold'), ('mom', 'dad', 'car'), ('mom', 'dad', 'escape')...]
```

but what I really want is a .txt file like:

```
mom dad kid\n
mom dad house\n
mom dad car\n
... etc
```

How do I either iterate permutations straight into human readable rows, or write/convert this existing list into a file? THANKS (first question ever!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for sent in it.permutations(wordlist, 3):
        outfile.write(f"{' '.join(sent)}\n")
```

Comment: Does the fstring has any advantage over `outfile.write(' '.join(sent) + '\n')`? Seems somewhat harder to read to me.

Comment: @LeMinaw/l No particular advantage aside from not making a huge temporary string before the write